# How to specify column types for CTE (Common Table Expressions) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Consider

```
WITH t (f0, f1) as (
  values 
     (1, 10),
     (2, 20)     
)...
```

How do I specify that f0 and f1 are of type bigint?

Comment: A CTE is not a stand a lone structure but rather a TSQL shortcut.  If you want a stand alone structure then TVP or #TEMP.

Comment: @Blam: CTEs are not specific to SQL-Server/TSQL, they are part of the SQL standard.

Comment: @muistooshort - then I mis-understood the question or not sure what is asked, removing my comments. Wanted to point out through the link that might be explicit datatype will cause datatype mis-match, anyways, Thanks for pointing it out, cheers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you'd have to specify the types inside the VALUES expression in your case:

```
WITH t (f0, f1) as (
  values 
     (1::bigint, 10::bigint),
     (2, 20)
)...
```

You only need the types on the first set of values, PostgreSQL can infer the rest.

For example, suppose we have two functions:

```
create function f(bigint, bigint) returns bigint as $$
begin
    raise notice 'bigint';
    return $1 * $2;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create function f(int, int) returns int as $$
begin
    raise notice 'int';
    return $1 * $2;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then

```
WITH t (f0, f1) as (
    values
        (1, 10),
        (2, 20)
)
select f(f0, f1) from t;
```

will give you two `int` notices whereas

```
WITH t (f0, f1) as (
    values
        (1::bigint, 10::bigint),
        (2, 20)
)
select f(f0, f1) from t;
```

would give you two `bigint` notices.

Comment: You only need the type cast on the first row: `(1::bigint, 10::bigint), (2, 20)` works as you'd expect. (All values in a single column are a single type.) pgAdmin displays the resulting data type in the output tab.

Comment: @Catcall: Yeah, that makes sense, columns being columns and all.

Comment: Thank you @muistooshort, it works! What I found super strange is that the error I was getting was "operator does not exist: bigint = text", which is somewhat unexpected (your result of int makes sense). I'm calling this (with integer arguments) from epgsql (Erlang), so I'll just blame the driver for the time being.

I solved the issue by casting everything to bigint, but your solutions is way cleaner.

#Catcall -- makes sense, thanks for the tip!  It's probably more trouble than it's worth for the time being, considering that I'm building the query in Erlang.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I don't know any Erlang so I can't help you there. What were you doing with the CTE that triggered that error from PostgreSQL?

Comment: @muistooshort doing an upsert on a table with two bigints.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Hard to tell what's going on without being able to play with it. But it is working now so we can move on to more productive things :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for you, but casting the column you want to specify worked for me in DB2

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    'Apple' AS STRING1
    ,CAST('Orange' AS VARCHAR(10000)) AS STRING2
FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Provide additional information on how the method you mentioned helped you.