# Create temporary table with fixed values

Tags: sql, postgresql, temporary

How do I create a temporary table in PostgreSQL that has one column "AC" and consists of these 4-digit values:

- Zoom
- Inci
- Fend

In essence the table has more values, this should just serve as an example.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only need the temp table for one SQL query, then you can hard-code the data into a Common Table Expression as follows :

```
WITH temp_table AS
(
  SELECT 'Zoom' AS AC UNION
  SELECT 'Inci' UNION
  SELECT 'Fend'
)
SELECT * FROM temp_table
```

see it work at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f88ac/2
*(that CTE syntax also works with MS SQL)*
HTH

Comment: You don't need the complicated `select .. union`: `with temp_table (ac) as ( values ('Zoom'), ('Inci'), ('Fend') ) ..` is even shorter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one :)  More info here, regarding naming the columns and specifying types : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676805/how-to-specify-column-types-for-cte-common-table-expressions-in-postgresql

Comment: Note: VALUES is only available on SQL Server 2008 (v10) and later.

Comment: The question is for PostgreSQL. SQL Server limitations are not relevant